# How to compile css and jss in laravel mix

Tags: laravel, laravel-mix

How to compile css and jss in multi page application in laravel page wise using laravel mix . suppose i have page 1 , page 2 and page1 have test10.js, test11.js, test12.js and test10.css, test11.css,test12.css and page2 have test21.js, test22.js, test23.js and test21.css, test22.css,test23.css and so on. So someone let me know how to compile the css and jss in multipages applications.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/mix#introduction

Comment: thanks @Hussein for reply, i have searched over there but there is no any information in case of muli page applications so i have asked this question over here. some js will be common on both page page1 and page2 , but in some case few js will be differed . So How i can compile these js page wise.

Answer (score 1):

For most cases, it is a good practice to optimize a big chunk of your assets to work on almost all pages. It is not a big problem that some pieces are not getting used on every page because caching gives better performance results when you only use one file that stays the same on every page.

There is an option for compiling multiple assets. You can just call the `js()` or `sass()` or an other method an other time. This time referencing an other file that needs to be compiled. In your layout you can add them per page.

What I like to do is the following:

1. I add a `@stack('js)` to my main layout.
2. For every piece of Javascript that only needs to be included at a single page I use `@push('js)` and `@endpush`.
3. Sometimes, when the code gets to big to handle, I add a `js()` method in my `webpack.mix.js` file. This gives me more freedom in writing my javascript.

A stack has a big advantage: It accepts multiple entries. This comes in handy when you use partials to build up your view and you want to keep the Javascript logic in the same files.